# Tomcat 8.5 ignoring JarScanFilter settings in context.xml

Tags: tomcat

I'm attempting to improve Tomcat 8.5 startup performance for a specific application.  In order to do this, I am setting a `JarScanFilter` in the `META-INF/context.xml` file for the application, setting the TLD file scanner to only scan jar files that are actually relevant:

```
<Context>
  <JarScanner>
    <JarScanFilter
        tldScan="*jsptags*.jar,*taglib*.jar,*jstl*.jar,spring-webmvc*.jar"
        defaultTldScan="false"
        />
  </JarScanner>
</Context>
```

This configuration file is definitely being processed (as an early version had incorrect an attribute name, which was reported as expected in the server logs), but it doesn't seem to be having any effect: Tomcat is still processing a load of jar files that are not in my tldScan list.  The logs look like this:

```
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.921 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myprojectname.admin' did not find a matching property.
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.24
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 27 2017 13:05:30 UTC
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.24.0
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b18
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         F:\eclipse workspaces\myprojectname\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Development\apache-tomcat-8.5.24
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx600m
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=F:\eclipse workspaces\myprojectname\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Development\apache-tomcat-8.5.24
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=F:\eclipse workspaces\binco
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Development\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\endorsed
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=F:\eclipse workspaces\myprojectname\Servers\Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost-config\logging.properties
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:34.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;C:\HDD\Haskell\7.10.2-a\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\HDD\Haskell\7.10.2-a\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\gtkmm-3-vs-2013\bin;C:\HDD\Haskell\7.10.2-a\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin;C:\hdd\geda\gEDA\bin;C:\hdd\geda\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin;c:\hdd\z88dk\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\HDD\lattice\ispcpld\bin;C:\HDD\lattice\ispFPGA\bin\nt;C:\HDD\lattice\active-hdl\BIN;C:\Users\admin\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\admin\.windows-build-tools\python27\scripts;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;C:\HDD\Haskell\7.10.2-a\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\HDD\Haskell\7.10.2-a\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\gtkmm-3-vs-2013\bin;C:\HDD\Haskell\7.10.2-a\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\hdd\esp8266\bin;C:\Users\admin\A;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\system32;;.]
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:35.435 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:35.610 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:35.623 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:35.637 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:35.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1995 ms
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:35.695 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:35.695 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.24
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:36.215 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:36.215 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/resources.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:36.230 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:36.230 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:36.230 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jce.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:36.230 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/charsets.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:04:36.230 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jfr.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.920 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.937 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.937 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/resources.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.937 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/resources.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.937 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jce.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jce.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/charsets.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/charsets.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jfr.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:57.984 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jfr.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:58.000 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:58.367 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [316] milliseconds.
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/annotations-api.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/catalina-ant.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/catalina-ha.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/catalina-storeconfig.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/catalina-tribes.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/catalina.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/ecj-4.6.3.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/el-api.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/jasper-el.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/jasper.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/jaspic-api.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/jsp-api.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.223 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/servlet-api.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.224 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-api.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.224 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-jni.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-util-scan.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-util.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/lib/websocket-api.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/resources.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jce.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/charsets.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/jfr.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/bin/bootstrap.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.240 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Development/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/bin/tomcat-juli.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:05:59.256 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Scanning JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/lib/tools.jar] from classpath
    20-Nov-2018 17:10:37.688 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
```